# Write GPIO value from Android application using Binder

Tags: java, android

I want to change the value of a GPIO from an Android application on android 4.2.2.

I tried using an application with JNI but I can not write to the value file. The reason is that only the root is able to write to this file and the application runs with some user permission given by the android am or the system user. None of them can write to the value file.

A possible solution is to create a native daemon and have the app communicate with it through sockets. But this will load my system and I am not sure if it is secure.

Another solution would be to create a server and a client process and have them communicate through a Binder. The client would be my application and it would send commands to the server.

My question is: what type of process should the server be in order to be able to have the root permissions and also to be used with Binder and my android app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your own custom ROM you could do this via the daemon or custom service, as you noted.  Either way would work and wouldn't impact the system CPU load, if done correctly.  Using a service and `Binder` is the typical way this is done in Android and how nearly all of the system services work.  You need to be careful, though.  Not only could this open up a security hole in your system (allowing any app to bind to your service and therefore "talk" to the kernel), but you also could inadvertently violate the CDD if you make your service part of the Android namespace.  Your service or daemon would have to be a process run as the 'system' user on your ROM in order to gain access to the kernel exposed device handle.  If started via init this is easy to do.  See the `init.rc` documentation or an existing one for an example.